# datatables floating left some dom

Tags: datatables

I have a dom like:

```
dom:'<lf>rt<ip><B><"clear">',
```

But I want to have `l` and `i` need to be floating on left, because with the actual dom config I have a table like this:

```
 l-----
 -----f
 r
 TABLE
 i----
 ----p
 B----
```

My goal is to have it like:

```
 l----f
 r
 TABLE
 i---p
 B----
```

How should I setup the dom for that?

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I did it with:

```
dom:'<"row"<"col-sm-6"l><"col-sm-6"f>>rt<"row"<"col-sm-6"i><"col-sm-6"p>>B<"clear">',
```